# Equivalent of url() helper function in Zend controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In the Zend view helper, there is the function url() for outputting a URL based on the routing tables eg

```
$this->url(array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add')
```

How can I do the same thing in a controller? In particular I want to set the action URL for a Zend Form using controller/action syntax rather than a standard URL eg

```
$form = new Zend_Form;
$form->setMethod('post')->setAction( $this->url(array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add')) );
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an action helper for this: [`Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url`](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/classes/Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url.html). Inside an action controller, you can access it using:

```
$this->_helper->url($action [, $controller [, $module [, $params]]]);
```

or:

```
$this->_helper->url->url(array(...));
```

Alternatively, you can also use the view helper:

```
$this->view->url(...);
```

Comment: If I call `$this->_helper->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'download'))` outside the IndexController (here AjaxController) it returns *'/ajax/Array'* what did I do wrong? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Use `$this->_helper->url('download', 'index')` or `$this->_helper->url->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'download'))`. I will update my answer and add a link to the API docs.

Answer (score 3):

I've actually found out that only this works:

```
// in your form
public function init()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $url = $router->assemble(
        array(
            'paramterName0' => 'parameterValue0',
            'paramterName1' => 'parameterValue1',
        ),
        'routeName'
    );

    $this->setAction($url);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was able to answer my own question as it seems the following code does the trick:-

```
$form = new Zend_Form;
$form->setMethod('post')->setAction( $this->getHelper('url')->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'add')) );
```

Comment: I now use `$this->view->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'download'))`, not nice but works inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In zf3 you can use:

```
    $form = new YourFormClass();
    $form->setMethod('post')->setAction($this->url()->fromRoute(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'add'));
```